# Can't create cron job in Google App Engine app that has multiple services

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

When I deploy my application which has multiple services, I can't see the cron job to be registered in App Engine Console, despite following directory hierarchy described in [Configuration files overview](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configuration-files) .

This is my `cron.xml` file, which I placed in my default service's `WEB-INF` directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/cron</url>
        <description>Execute scheduled tasks</description>
        <schedule>every 5 minutes</schedule>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

This is my default service's `appengine-web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>default</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

  <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>

  <manual-scaling>
    <instances>1</instances>
  </manual-scaling>
</appengine-web-app>
```

My GAE application has 4 services, all defined in `application.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
  <display-name>modules-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>module-default-1.0</web-uri>
      <context-root>module-default</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>module-1-1.0</web-uri>
      <context-root>module-1</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <!-- declared other modules likewise -->
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

My project structure:

[image: This is my project structure]

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong that my cron job doesn't run?

Comment: seems like you followed the document very well. try to go to the URL and whether you are getting any error or anything in the app engine logs.

Comment: Well, as this url is registered under web.xml, by doing it I just simply manually run the cron handler. No errors.

Comment: so that mean your cron job is ran successfully? Did you check on the queue list of the app engine?

Comment: Cron job runing successfully would mean that they run automatically, right? 
I checked the logs and they show that cron fires only when I manually run /cron. And this is normal, cause the cron handler is just another servlet which is registered in web.xml under /cron url

Comment: are you talking about your local development server or about the App Engine productive server? Cron Jobs do not run automatically at local development server

Comment: I know that. As I already wrote: cron doesn't swow up in App Engine Console Dashboard, so I'm talking about productive server.

Comment: ok, I see. Your cron job should run in the default module?

Comment: Exactly. That's why I put cron.xml in default module's WEB-INF folder.

Comment: I just see a small difference between your and my configuration. I put my application id into the tag application of my default appengine-web.xml and not the module name. I even did not put the tag module into my default appengine-web.xml

Comment: I didn't quite get that. Would you mind please to show the exact difference between our configurations?

Comment: you wrote <application>default</application> into your default appengine-web.xml and I have <application>the-id-of-my-appengine-project-and-not-the-name-of-the-module</application>

Answer (score 1):

Try deploying cron configuration in a separate command:

1. If you're using [gcloud cli](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy): `gcloud app deploy cron.yaml`
2. Or [gradle appengine plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin#tasks): `./gradlew appengineUpdateCron`
3. Or [maven appengine plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven#application_management_goals): `mvn appengine:update_cron`

I had the same problem and running the command after the deployment solved it!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is an old issue, so if I'm not mistaken I think we tried it too, but I don't remember precisely. I'll try it later and see.